# Does Eclipse have a GUI builder out-of-the-box?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse for Android coding. I wanted to make another version of my application for Desktops, but couldn't find any option to add a JFrame layout or something.

I found out that there's a plugin provided by Google called "Window Builder", and a variety of other plugins, but in Netbeans I don't have to download any kind of plugin, it comes with it.

Does Eclipse have a GUI-building support out-of-the-box (without any plugins)?

Comment: There are several different Eclipse downloads available on eclipse.org some of which include WindowBuilder. So if you want a GUI builder download one of those (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers for example).

Comment: @greg-449 So I'll be using Google's, right? I mean it will be the same as downloading Eclipse Standard then downloading Google's plugin.

Comment: Netbeans for gui - eclipse for coding ^^

Comment: [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com) rulez 'em all. For me it's better than any GUI builder, YMMV, but you might want to have a look at the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need a plugin for that.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse RCP - Rich Client Platform is the library you are looking for, this is a getting started [tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=423).

RCP is the eclipse based Swing like library used to build eclipse itself, similar to the Netbeans Platfom.